# Consuming Salesforce outbound message using Spring Integration

Tags: salesforce, spring-integration, spring-ws

I want to consume Salesforce Outbound Message using Spring and process them sequentially and persist the data in MySQL database. Also I have to send a success response back to Salesforce after processing. I have the WSDL from Salesforce.Could any one provide me an approach on which Spring framework to use. Any examples or links would help me great.

Answer (score 0):

Since you gave WSDL, that means you work with SOAP WebService.

For this purpose Spring Integration provides WeService Adapters support: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.7.RELEASE/reference/html/ws.html

What you need is called WebService Inbound Gateway and here is some sample: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/ws-inbound-gateway

For storing data into RDBMS you need JDBC adapters: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.7.RELEASE/reference/html/jdbc.html

And here is a sample: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/jdbc